# Check if SSL certificate correspond to URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

We need to check the URL certified by an SSL Certificate.
For example, I check https://www.google.fr certificate and if there is an SSL error, I want to check if this URL is the one certified (ex : gaagle.fr instead of google.fr)

How can we retrieve it ?

Comment: What are you using to access the website? I’m fairly sure .net will already throw errors if response certificates aren’t valid for the request.

Comment: Typically you can use `SslStream` https://leastprivilege.com/2005/02/28/sslstream-sample/